# how to make a graph with unorder data without overlapping?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of unordered data
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0Fpi.jpg)

for example: scaffold 16 was started from 0.05 mbp to 0.85 mbp but scaffold 18 was started again from 0.05.
I am planning to make "Mbp" as X axis and "Pvalue" as Y axis. However, the scaffold data overlap each other.
Does anyone know how to make a graph with thise data witout overlapping each other?
This is my script

```
    #Chromosome 
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)


data1 = read.csv("data1.csv", header=T)
data2 = read.csv("data2.csv", header=T)

datas = bind_rows(
        data1 %>% mutate(row = row_number()) %>% mutate(df = "A"),
        data2 %>% mutate(row = row_number()) %>% mutate(df = "B"))


# fig theme ##############################################################

mytheme = theme_gray() + theme (panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
                                panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
                                panel.background = element_blank(), 
                                axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
                                legend.title=element_blank(),
                                axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),
                                axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20),
                                text = element_text(size=20),
                                axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=0)
                           
                       + annotate (geom = "rect", 
                                   color = "#D5D8DC", 
                                   fill = "#D5D8DC", alpha = 0.4)
)

theme_set(mytheme)

# Wiring fig ##############################################################
     
A = ggplot(datas, aes(Mbp, Pvalue, color = df))+ 
    geom_jitter(size = 1, alpha = 0.4, width = 0.2) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept=1.4,linetype="dashed") + 
    xlim(-0.1, 20) +
    ylim(0, 50) +
    ylab("-Log10(P)") + 
    xlab("") +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("#0F34E1", "orange"))
                       
A = A + ggtitle("Chromosom")
```

These are the data
[data1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C2wOUAtOc2NmSt4z7ErNMFjLu6DTyNhmVDqV_ToApbM/edit#gid=0)
[data2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11gXAFfTOm5mAnzEKzpwDdJ2qysxuwgW3_17FhQNH0Qo/edit#gid=0)

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to your problem is to separate the values for different 'scaffolds' into separate panels using `facet_grid()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Read in data from public google sheet.
googlesheets4::gs4_deauth()
data1 = googlesheets4::read_sheet("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C2wOUAtOc2NmSt4z7ErNMFjLu6DTyNhmVDqV_ToApbM/edit#gid=0",
                                  col_types="cnn")

plot1 = ggplot(data1, aes(x=Mbp, y=Pvalue)) +
        theme_bw() + 
        geom_point(size=2, alpha=0.5) + 
        geom_hline(yintercept=1.4, linetype="dashed") + 
        ylab("-Log10(P)") +
        facet_grid(. ~ Scaffold)

ggsave("plot1.png", plot=plot1, width=8, height=3, dpi=150)
```

[image]